# populate text box on one form based on combo box selection on another form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I've been looking around and can't seem to find an accurate answer to at least steer me in the right direction. On form1 (Members) i have a button that opens another form (supervisor) with a combo. The combo has 3 fields and upon selection I want it to store the 3 values in a text box on form1 then close form 2 (which I know this code).

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the Form, Use the Vba code as below

```
Forms![MEMBER].Textbox1= Me.Combobox1  ' set the value of combobox to your Textbox in Form1
Docmd.close 'Close the form
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn’t work. I’ll double check my code, but I’m sure that’s exactly what I have... well plus with the other two fields

Comment: Forms![MEMBER].Textbox1= Me.Combo0.Column(1). try this

Comment: yeah that worked, still trying to figure out how to get all thre fields into one single text box though.

Comment: that's easy `Forms![MEMBER].Textbox1 = Me.Combo1.Column(1) & " " & Me.Combo2.Column(1) & " " & Me.Combo3.Column(1)` change the combox Name and column index value as your need.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value on form1, use the `Column` property of `Combobox` with index value,

```
Forms!form1!Textbox1 = Me.Combobox1.Column(0) & " " & Me.Combobox1.Column(1) & " " & Me.Combobox1.Column(2)
```

Comment: I have this, the issue is I'm wanting to store Column(0), Column(1), and Column(2) into one text box, with a space beteween each.

Answer (score -2):

nevermind I was able to figure it out once my brain started working...

```
Dim supervisor1 As Variant
Dim supervisor2 As Variant
Dim supervisor3 As Variant
Dim supervisor4 As Variant

supervisor1 = Me.Combo0.Column(0)
supervisor2 = Me.Combo0.Column(1)
supervisor3 = Me.Combo0.Column(2)
supervisor4 = supervisor1 & " " & supervisor3 & " " & supervisor2
Forms![Member].Text48 = supervisor4
```